# What are idiomatic terms for "out-of-class knowledge"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I am trying to say that I used knowledge beyond what has been taught in the classroom, things I have learned from extra readings or research on my own. I can think of a couple possible terms but they don't seem idiomatic.

> In the report, I used *out-of-class knowledge points / beyond-textbook knowledge*.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the word **outside** there. You drew on **outside knowledge**.  It is a well-worn collocation as shown [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22outside%20knowledge%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

Answer (score 0):

This question has an answer in english stackexchange.

https://english.stackexchange.com/a/146909

But that doesn't look so right here. So I would suggest

> autodidact

auto means "self" and "didact" comes from the Greek word for "teach," so an autodidact is a person who's self-taught.

Source: [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/autodidact)